# Не работает кастомное ЧПУ в MODx

Tags: .htaccess, modx

Добрый день. Нужно чтобы ссылки вида

> htttp://www.site.ru/company.html?name=bestcompany

заменялись ссылкой

> htttp://www.site.ru/company/bestcompany.html

Прошу подсказать где я ошибся. Что делал:

Написал соответственно:

```
RewriteRule ^company/([^/]*)\.html$ /company?name=$1 [L]
```

Стоит Modx. .htaccess в корне, friendly url работают, полный код .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site\.ru [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^company/([^/]*)\.html$  /company.html?name=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы ошиблись в порядке правил.

Вот эта часть:

```
# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Срабатывает раньше вашего правила:

```
RewriteRule ^company/([^/]*)\.html$  /company.html?name=$1 [L]
```

Если ввести `htttp://www.site.ru/company/bestcompany.html`, то после стандартных правил исходный URL имеет вид: `http://www.site.ru/index.php?q=company/bestcompany.html` и не удовлетворяет условиям вашего редиректа.

Решение проблемы очень простое: поменять местами редиректы. Вот так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site\.ru [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^company/([^/]*)\.html$  /company.html?name=$1 [L]

# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

После этого все должно заработать.